# Standalone Atmega328p-pu not working without external crystal

Tags: arduino

Recently i bought some standalone Atmega328p-pu (just the MC not a arduino board). At the time i forgot to buy a 16mhz crystal but according to many sources on the internet i could run it without the crystal. but it never worked. I used a Arduino Nano as the programmer (with the Arduino as ISP sketch). made the following connections.

```
Nano ---> Atmega328p-pu
D13       Pin 19 (SCK)
D12       Pin 18 (MISO)
D11       Pin 17 (MOSI)
D10       Pin 1  (RESET) (tried it with and without a pullup resistor to 5V).
5V        VCC
```

with those connections when i try to burn the bootloader or upload sketch using programmer, my upload fails. i get Device signature 0x000000. i have tested this on other MCs as well and none of them worked. few days later i bought a 16mhz crystal and connected it as given bellow. (keeping previous connections as they were).

```
Crystal Pin 1 ---> Pin 9  (XTAL 1)
Crystal Pin 2 ---> Pin 10 (XTAL 2)
22nF capacitor between the pins and ground
```

Only after this did the my MC work. i could burn the bootloader and upload code to the Atmega328p-pu using my Nano as the programmer

So. the question is **why was the Atmega328p-pu not working without the crystal?** i have seen videos on youtube where a crystal was not used and the MC worked fine.

Note: when i say MCs i mean other Atmega328p-pu's

Comment: First, you may not need an crystal as long as you have an oscillator or other signal source that can generate the [clock signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_signal). The crystal is needed to generate the clock signal which is used to synchronise the operation of various parts within the ATMega328p. Crystal is like the heart, and the clock signal is like the heart beat of a human body, without it a CPU will simply not working.

Comment: Having said that ATMega328p do have a way for you to choose an internal clock source rather than using the external crystal.

Comment: [This](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/16735/40646) provide a good explanation to your question.

Comment: so basically the Atmega328p will use the internal clock only if the fuse bits are set correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Using the external clock or internal clock depend on the fuse settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without external clock, you can just have 8MHz. With a crystal, you arrive to 16MHz.

If you use the one from an Arduino board, it is already programmed and it will not work without a crystal (you can put any crystal to upload your sketch, from 100kHz to 12MHz).

But it is important that you never upload a sketch with external crystal fuse flag set. Because at this point, you need to connect a crystal to pins 9 to 10 (also by hand) to be able to start/program it again.

Arduino IDE has the default Arduino boards. If you have your own AtMega328, you should install this board:
https://github.com/MCUdude/MiniCore

Then you can just set your 328 with the custom crystal settings:
[image]

If you set the interal crystal (limited to 8MHz), you can use pin 9 and 10 for other purposes.

Comment: I was able to get the internal clock working following your post. Did the initial upload with the 16mhz crystal. then the 328p worked flawlessly without the crystal. thanks alot.

Comment: I did find another solution which is more terminal friendly.
again primarily having the 16mhz crystal set the lfuse to use the internal 8MHz.

following this instructables it was fairly easy.
https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-change-fuse-bits-of-AVR-Atmega328p-8bit-mic/

Comment: If you upload the sketch with the crystal, your 328p will never start up again without an external crystal. This is the main problem. So you can not upload another sketch with a 8MHz fuse flag. The only way is to put a crystal over the 2 pins to have a clock (so your 328p begins to work) until you set the new fuse flag.